# Get list of (floored) hours between two DateTimes

Tags: c#

I wrote a function to inclusively give me a list of hours that fall between two `DateTime`'s.

But in the end it doesn't really look very easy to read and it makes me want to unit test it even though the project I'm working on doesn't unit test at all.

So my question is, is there a more legible and or efficient way to write this?:

Code:

```
private List<DateTime> GetHoursForEvent(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var hours = new List<DateTime>();

    DateTime startFloor = Convert.ToDateTime(start.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:00:00"));
    DateTime endFloor = Convert.ToDateTime(end.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:00:00"));

    for (double dblDate = startFloor.ToOADate(); 
         dblDate <= endFloor.ToOADate(); 
         dblDate += (1.0 / 24.0))
    {
        hours.Add(DateTime.FromOADate(dblDate));
    }

    return hours;
}
```

Input:

```
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-04-01 04:22:00");
DateTime end   = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-04-02 00:05:00");
```

Result:

```
2012-04-01 04:00:00
2012-04-01 05:00:00
2012-04-01 06:00:00
2012-04-01 07:00:00
2012-04-01 08:00:00
2012-04-01 09:00:00
2012-04-01 10:00:00
2012-04-01 11:00:00
2012-04-01 12:00:00
2012-04-01 13:00:00
2012-04-01 14:00:00
2012-04-01 15:00:00
2012-04-01 16:00:00
2012-04-01 17:00:00
2012-04-01 18:00:00
2012-04-01 19:00:00
2012-04-01 20:00:00
2012-04-01 21:00:00
2012-04-01 22:00:00
2012-04-01 23:00:00
2012-04-02 00:00:00
```

I get the feeling i'm reinventing the wheel.

Comment: If possible, it might be better to return an `IEnumerable<DateTime>` rather than a list.  You can always call `ToList` if you really need a list, and it allows for the potential of not generating every single result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, something like this should work better for you:

```
private List<DateTime> GetHoursForEvent(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var hours = new List<DateTime>();
    var current = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, start.Day, start.Hour, 0, 0);
    while(current <= end)
    {
        hours.Add(current);
        current = current.AddHours(1);
    }
    return hours;
}
```

You may even want to make this into a streaming method, unless there's a specific reason you need to return a `List`:

```
private IEnumerable<DateTime> GetHoursForEvent(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var current = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, start.Day, start.Hour, 0, 0);
    while(current <= end)
    {
        yield return current;
        current = current.AddHours(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although there is no constructor I am aware of that takes 4 int arguments, so I should probably be `new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, start.Day, start.Hour, 0 , 0)`

Comment: This should also deal with daylight savings jumps correctly, unlike the code in the OP.

Comment: Sheesh, tons better.. Thank you.  (Including suggesting using IEnumerable and avoid DST bug)

Answer (score 1):

Try use this code

```
private List<DateTime> GetHoursForEvent(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        List<DateTime> hours = new List<DateTime>();
        while (start < end)
        {
            hours.Add(start);
            start = start.AddHours(1);
        }
        return hours;
    }
```